Linear isotropy group at the origin of a homogeneous space
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a compact subgroup. I am trying to understand Example 1.3 in Kobayashi & Nomizu's "Foundations..." , in Chapter IV.1. They say we consider the linear isotropy group $\tilde H$ at the origin $o$ of $G/H$, where $o$ is the coset $H$; they don't describe further how this is defined.
I am tempted to think that to define this, we start with the group $G_H := \{ g \in G: gH = H \}$. Then the differential of the multiplication with an element of $G_H$ maps the tangent space at any point of $H$ to the tangent space at another point of $H$, so intuitively it should indeed give a linear isomorphism on $T_o (G/H)$. But I'm having trouble defining it rigorously, first of all because I don't quite know how to describe elements of $T_o (G/H)$. I'm tempted to say a vector $T_o (G/H)$ is of the form $X + TH$, where $X \in T_e G$ ($e$ = the identity of $G$). But this doesn't even make sense to me, since the bundle $TH$ consists of vectors at other points than $e$...

treat the tangent space as the lie algebra $g/h$?

Your first sentence is wrong: $G/K$ typically is not a Lie group (is not even homeomorphic to one).

@MoisheKohan This makes matters worse then. How can I make sense of Example 1.3, then?

$G$ acts on the space $G/H$ from the left. The subgroup $H\subset G$ preserves the point $o=[H]$, i.e. for any $h\in H$ you have $ho=o$. Then the differential $d_0h:T_oG/H\to T_oG/H$ is a linear map, you can check that $d_o h' d_oh = d_o(h' h)$ for any $h',h\in H$. This gives you a group homomorphism $H\to GL(T_oG/H)$. The image of this homomorphism is what I would call the linear isotropy group of $o$ in $G/H$.
